# Split DAG into disjoint sets

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, complexity

I wrote an algorithm to separate a DAG into disjoint sets of vertices. I was hoping to have some comments on algorithmic complexity and efficiency of the Python code. Notably, I don't like the adding and removing of components from the components list.

```
g = {1: [3, 4], 2: [5], 3:[7], 4:[], 5:[], 6:[1], 7:[]}

vertices = set(g)
components = []
while vertices:
  stack = list((vertices.pop(),))
  comp = set()
  while stack:
    vert = stack.pop()
    comp.add(vert)
    if vert in vertices:
       vertices.remove(vert)
    for e in g[vert]:
        if e in vertices:
            stack.append(e)
        else:
            for component in components:
               if e in component:
                  component.update(comp)
                  comp = component
                  components.remove(comp)
    components.append(comp)

print([c for c in components])
```

`>>> [{2, 5}, {1, 3, 4, 6, 7}]`

Answer (score 1):

It would seem to me that one way to solve this is to change all the *directed* arcs in the dag to *undirected* edges. The rest is to recognize the disjoint subgraphs using breadth-first search:

```
def convert_directed_graph_to_undirected_graph(graph):
    """Converts each directed arc into an undirected edge."""
    undirected_graph = {}
    for node, child_node_list in graph.items():
        if node not in undirected_graph.keys():
            undirected_graph[node] = []
        undirected_graph[node].extend(child_node_list)
        for child_node in child_node_list:
            if child_node not in undirected_graph.keys():
                undirected_graph[child_node] = []
            undirected_graph[child_node].append(node)
    return undirected_graph


def crawl_subgraph(source_node, undirected_graph, visited):
    """Implements breadth-first search in order to find the entire subgraph including the source noe."""
    if source_node in visited:
        return None
    visited.add(source_node)
    queue = deque([source_node])
    subgraph = [source_node]
    while queue:
        current_node = queue.popleft()
        for neighbor_node in undirected_graph[current_node]:
            if neighbor_node not in visited:
                visited.add(neighbor_node)
                subgraph.append(neighbor_node)
                queue.append(neighbor_node)
    return subgraph


def find_disjoint_dags(graph):
    """Finds all disjoint subdags in the input dag."""
    undirected_graph = convert_directed_graph_to_undirected_graph(graph)
    visited = set()
    disjoint_subgraphs = []
    vertices = set(undirected_graph)
    for vertex in vertices:
        subgraph = crawl_subgraph(vertex, undirected_graph, visited)
        if subgraph:
            disjoint_subgraphs.append(subgraph)
    return disjoint_subgraphs
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I know this approach as Tarjan's algorithm. However, I am trying to avoid the conversion to an undirected graph. I feel like I was able to circumvent that with keeping sets of components. I was looking for comments on that approach.

Comment: @shane Fair enough. However, note that this is not Tarjan's algorithm, since Tarjan's algorithm is about computing strongly connected components of a directed **graph**, which is different from your problem setting.

Comment: Ahh, yep you are correct

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Union-Find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). Every edge in your graph represents elements from two subsets that you want to merge. Once you have completed the merges constructing the sets is trivial. When implemented with *union by rank* and *path compression* the algorithm runs in **O(n)** time:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# Find ancestor and compress the path along the way
def find_ancestor(parent, vertex):
    if parent[vertex] != vertex:
        parent[vertex] = find_ancestor(parent, parent[vertex])

    return parent[vertex]

# Merge sets in case given vertices are not in same set already
def merge(parent, rank, v1, v2):
    v1 = find_ancestor(parent, v1)
    v2 = find_ancestor(parent, v2)

    if v1 != v2:
        if rank[v2] > rank[v1]:
            v1, v2 = v2, v1

        parent[v2] = v1
        rank[v1] += rank[v2]

def disjoint_sets(graph):
    parent = {k: k for k in graph}
    rank = {k: 1 for k in graph}

    # Iterate over edges, for every edge merge vertices
    for vertex, neighbors in graph.items():
        for n in neighbors:
            merge(parent, rank, vertex, n)

    # Group vertices based on the component
    components = defaultdict(list)
    for vertex in graph:
        components[find_ancestor(parent, vertex)].append(vertex)

    return components.values()

g = {1: [3, 4], 2: [5], 3:[7], 4:[], 5:[], 6:[1], 7:[]}
print(disjoint_sets(g))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 3, 4, 6, 7], [2, 5]]
```